# Como ir ao chat?

Tags: suporte, chat

Falam tanto desse tal do chat, mas não sei como ir lá, não tem nenhum botão na página inicial nem nada... Enfim, como vou pra lá e escolho o canal pra onde eu vou?

Comment: Intrigas da oposição, o que o pessoal tá falando mesmo é d[esse tal de roque enrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTfChW-PBts).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No lado direito do menu superior, clique no ultimo icone, ao aparecer o menu verá o chat, como na imagem:

[image: Acesso ao chat via menu (stack-exchange-button) do site]

Pode também buscar o [**Estouro de Pilha**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) digitando *"estouro"* no box de *filter rooms* que aparece (entre outras salas):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Já que estamos no espirito FAQ, ia ser legal se mostrasse como ir pra sala Estouro de Pilha: `como escolho o canal pra onde eu vou?`

Comment: @brasofilo nah, você já está querendo demais :P

Comment: Não, tava falando sério :D

Comment: @brasofilo Heheheh, bom agora você já adicionou os prints

Comment: faq, my friend, faq