# O que fazer com edições potencialmente ofensivas?

Tags: debate

Hoje, no Stack Overflow, foi feita uma pergunta sobre [websockets genérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424426/como-conectar-raw-sockets-tcp-com-websockets-pendente-%C3%A9-o-caralho), que foi marcada como pendente pela comunidade por ser considerada fora do escopo. Até aí, tudo bem, mas o usuário editou o título da pergunta para **Como conectar Raw Sockets (TCP) com WebSockets? [Pendente é o caralho] [pendente]**:

[image: pergunta com título impróprio]

Nesses casos, onde a pergunta já foi sinalizada anteriormente, qual o procedimento correto a se tomar?

Comment: **Edite com ROLLBACK** (para voltar a versão anterior) e **sinalize** para um moderador, citando quem foi o usuário que editou de preferencia. Pronto, quem deve tomar conta disto é quem pode punir (moderador) e **evite se envolver** ou tentar orientar, a maioria que tentei orientar já estavam tão nervosos quando cheguei que mesmo eu não tendo nada haver acabei pagando o pato.

Comment: **PS:** reverti: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/424426/revisions, não sinalizei pq um moderador já deu uma suspensão para o usuário em questão e "até o momento" a situação está resolvida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinalizar é o adequado sempre. Se estiver impedido de sinalizar por um motivo pode usar uma sinalização que requer atenção dos moderadores. Se não for possível e não se importar em aparecer como o denunciante pode entrar no chat e falar com os mais ativos que podem ver o que fazer, ou pode contatar algum moderador em comentário em alguma postagem dele (se for usado parcimoniosamente e para o bem pode fazer, não será considerado abuso).

A edição costuma ser boa, mas me enganou, eu achei até que era uma sinalização equivocada porque não vi abuso. Não cheguei recusar, mas não tomei providências na hora.

Se desejar apagar esta pergunta para não aparecer como denunciante nós entendemos.

Comment: Você falou sobre o chat. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com é só entrar, você tem reputação suficiente para isto. Geralmente o pessoal interage mais no "estouro de pilha"

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4740/3635